# Is it a good idea to create schema types to organize the relationships of tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Is it a good idea to create a schema type to separate the table relationships. I guess when you are browsing the tables in SSMS you will see them group together by schema type. But is it worth the trouble? Anyone with experience with this in real world scenarios?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen it called a  "schema type" .

Comment: what have you seen it called Jonh?

Comment: I have heard it called "schema"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've generally found that to be more of a hassle than any help it's provided. What do you do with tables that are relevant to multiple areas? What happens when a table seems to belong to one area but later migrates to another area of the application? Do you change its schema and refactor all of your code?

I have used multiple schemata to make delineations when there is a **VERY** clear boundary between objects, but usually not something like what you have in your diagram. One example is objects which are used just for DBA support. I might put those into their own schema if they aren't used by the actual application itself.

Comment: Thank you, those are things I did not think about